# Java Return is Returning Blank

Tags: java, methods, return

I'm trying to create a java method that returns the sum of two values x and y. Currently when I run the code, the output isn't returning anything. Is there any way I can get the value to return the sum WITHOUT modifying the "getSum(x,y);" in line 6 while using the return method???

```
public class ZawMethods2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int x = 7, y = 45; 
    getSum(x,y);
  }
  public static int getSum(int x, int y){
    int sum = x+y; 
    return (sum); 
  }
}
```

Thank you all in advance!!! I'm still in the beginning stage of coding so I appreciate all the help.

Comment: How do you know it's blank? You don't have anything to store the return value, nor do you have any printlines.

Comment: what do you mean: returning blank? because it doesn't print anything? just add a print statement

Comment: Are you asking why this program does not create any output?

Comment: Yes, the program compiles but it doesn't output anything

Comment: If you want to output the value to the console then you should use : System.out.println(getSum(x.y));

Comment: @Yunnosch how is that modifying that? it doesn't modify the call, it just changes what happens to the result of it

Comment: @Yunnosch You are very irritating.

Comment: @Yunnosch he may be referring to the internal working inside the method.

Comment: If I am irritating people who post without noticing part of the question or ingoring it or making assumptions on how exactly an explicit (though vague) requirement is made - then I think I am doing a good job.

Comment: @Yunnosch But copying the same sentence and pasting it 2 times is quite irritating...

Comment: @Yunnosch the question states: change nothing about that part, it doesn't say: don't change that line. you are making assumptions here yourself. unless you yourself think you are irritating, according to your statement, you're not doing a good job

Comment: @Stultuske Please elaborate the assumption I am making in your opinion.

Comment: @Yunnosch Actually I didn't modify the call to the method (line 6) but just added a print statement in the getSum() method which worked. Thanks for the help though

Comment: @Yunnosch re-read my post, it's explained there. otherwise, read zawl's response. putting a print statement around it, doesn't actually change the method call. You assume that the OP meant "don't change anything in this entire statement"

Comment: @Stultuske I did not assume that. It turned however out to be what OP meant. However, everybody proposing to change the line and add a print did assume that editing the line was allowed. Do not confuse making no assumption with making the opposite assumption.

Comment: @Yunnosch according to the OP's responses here, that is not what he meant. since he states, and I quote: "Yunnosch Actually I didn't modify the call to the method (line 6) but just added a print statement in the getSum() method which worked. Thanks for the help though" -> this shows it was a (wrong) assumption on your account.

Comment: @Stultuske Would you like to invite me to a chat?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I thought that you are not allowed to modify `getSum` method. Just add `System.out.println(sum);` to `getSum` method.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you! Just one question: was the problem with my code is that is it because the 'return' doesn't output/ print anything that we'd have to always include a print statement to get the output?

Comment: Yes, ```return``` has nothing to do with the output.

Comment: @CarolineZaw java never prints anything to the console unless you tell it to, with a `System.out.println` statement

Answer (score 3):

```
public class ZawMethods2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int x = 7, y = 45; 
    System.out.print(getSum(x,y));
  }
  public static int getSum(int x, int y){
    //no need to create temprory varibale 
    return x+y; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: If you create a temporary variable, it will get an extra memory in heap, that we should not do if we are not using that variable for any reference

Answer (score 2):

Just print it inside the `getSum` method, before returning:

```
public static int getSum(int x, int y){
    int sum = x+y; 
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum; 
}
```

As mentioned by @Stultuske in the comments. if you want to only print the sum, and never *get* it. Then just remove the return type and aswell name the method differently for clarification:

```
public static void printSum(int x, int y){
    System.out.println(x + y);
}
```

You might even want to introduce a whole new method. Leaving the old `getSum` all on itself. The new method then delegates and just prints the result returned:

```
public static void printSum(int x, int y){
    System.out.println(getSum(x, y));
}
```

Comment: then why not removing the return(type)?

Comment: @Stultuske this may not be the only use of `getSum` it may just be a simplified example. But yes if it *is* the only case then the removal might be worth it.

Comment: which is the point. if there are several usages, who says the OP wants that output to be printed for all of them?

Comment: @Stultuske another good point. One might want to introduce 2 methods then? 1 for getting and the other for printing. The latter calls the former. Which would probably be the cleanest way

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are compiling a program without any output. You have to use something like

> System.out.println(getSum(x, y));

Otherwise you wont get any output.

If you modify the main-method like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 7, y = 45; 
        int sum = getSum(x,y);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

you will get the output: *52*.
In this case you will save the returned Integer in sum and will print a new line to your console.
If you want to add some words, you can modify the main like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int x = 7, y = 45; 
    int sum = getSum(x,y);
    System.out.println("The result is" + sum);
}
```

Comment: @Yunnosch you notice any changes at the getSum method ? Thanks.

Comment: I notice (now with additional clarification by OP) that you changed exactly the part which was not to be changed. Previously I noticed that you made assumptions on what is allowed and what not and tried to make you aware of the part of the question which could be interpreted as forbidding explicitly what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your result in a variable or display a result.

```
int c = getSum(x,y);
```

or

```
System.out.println("The result of the two numbers are " +getSum(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public class ZawMethods2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 7, y = 45; 
        System.out.print(getSum(x,y));
    }
    public static int getSum(int x, int y)
    {
        int sum = x+y; 
        return (sum); 
    }
}
```

This code will resolve your problem very easily.